# Openshift: Get process namespace by process ID

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openshift-origin

Currently we have a situation where some applications running on our OpenShift cluster request very high resource load, and thus making the worker node they are running on unresponsive. 
However, we usually only see the process IDs when running `top` or similar tools on the affected node, plus the executable path, which is the encapsulated path in the pod.

Is there a chance that one can get the associated namespace to these processes which are only known by their PIDs?